# Restricting access to Swagger page in ASP.NET Web API 2 with NSwag

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nswag

I have ASP.NET Web API 2 and have configured Swagger using NSwag.
I want to restrict access to the Swagger page, expicially in the production environment.

It is my intention to incorporate a login authentication page, so I tried using ActionFilters, but no filter events are triggered when accessing the Swagger page.

Could you please advise on how I can achieve this?
Please let me know if I should provide more detail.

Thanks!